# Disable service based on Spring Boot /health status

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is it possible to disable Spring Integration handlers based on the status that's returned by the Actuator /health end point? In my Consul-orchestrated service, the Actuator health end point reports on the status of the connected Elasticsearch cluster. If the ES cluster is down, /health correctly reports that the service is DOWN, and so Consul marks the service as "critical" (and hence get's no REST calls). As the service is still running though, my listeners attached to a RabbitMQ queue are still invoked when messages exist on the queue.

Any ideas how I can disable these listeners if Spring Actuator is reporting my service as down?

Comment: Take a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553706/elasticsearch-health-check-failed-every-time-when-spring-boot-start-up/52539684#52539684